# Metodos get and set en python

Tags: python, get, set

Estoy haciendo este ejercicio que dice: Realizar un programa que conste de una clase llamada Alumno que tenga como atributos, el nombre y la nota del alumno.Definir los métodos para inicializar sus atributos, imprimirlos y mostrar un mensaje con el resultado de la nota y si ha aprobado o no.´

```
class Alumno():
    def __init__(self,nombre,nota):  #aqui defino mi clase y sus atributos, los cuales son encapsulados
      self._nombre=nombre
      self._nota=nota

def nombre(self): #metodo get para obtener el nombre del alumno
    return self.nombre

def nota(self):  #metodo get para obtener la nota del alumno
    return self._nota

def aprobacionNota(self, nota):   #metodo para saber si el alumno aprobo o no
    if self._nota > 9:
        print(f'aprobo su nota es {self._nota}')
    else:
        print(f'no aprobo su nota es {self._nota}')


alumno1=Alumno('Juana', 8)
print(alumno1.aprobacionNota(10))
```

ahora cuando lo ejecuto me sale que no aprobo, y abajo sale None, cual es la razon?
por otro lado si quito el ultimo print sale un error

Answer (score 2):

En esta línea invocas al método `aprobacionNota`

```
print(alumno1.aprobacionNota(10))
```

Ese método imprime el mensaje

```
no aprobo su nota es 8
```

y retorna sin entregar ningun valor, o sea `None`, que es lo que imprime la función `print`.

*Solución*

La solución rápida es eliminar el print, dejando simplemente la llamada al método.

```
alumno1.aprobacionNota(10)
```

Una mejor solución es sacar la impresión fuera de la función. La función ahora **retorna** un mensaje

```
def aprobacionNota(self, nota):   #metodo para saber si el alumno aprobo o no
    if self._nota > 9:
        return f'aprobo su nota es {self._nota}'
    else:
        return f'no aprobo su nota es {self._nota}'

alumno1=Alumno('Juana', 8)
print(alumno1.aprobacionNota(10))
```

Mejor aún es que la función se limite a hacer lo que dice su nombre (validar), y dejar que el llamante se encarge de realizar alguna acción al respecto:

```
def aprobacionNota(self, nota):   #metodo para saber si el alumno aprobo o no
    return self._nota > 9


alumno1=Alumno('Juana', 8)
if alumno1.aprobacionNota(10):
    print(f'aprobo su nota es {alumno1.nota()}')
else:
    print(f'no aprobo su nota es {alumno1.nota()}')
```

De esta manera ahora tienes la flexibilidad de llamar a la función de validación desde cualquier parte sin resultados adversos.

Comment: porque si le pasas 10 como parametro, sigue agarrando el 8??? ;)

Comment: @gbianchi. Porque no usa el parámetro para nada; ocupa el atributo de la clase.

Comment: interesante para agregar como nota en la respuesta...

Comment: la duda de @gbianchi es la misma que me hago yo, no deberia con este codigo alumno1=Alumno('Juana', 8) imprimir si aprobo o no la nota porque no lo imprime? si no hasta que hago esto print(alumno1.aprobacionNota(10))

Comment: no entendi tu respuesta @CandidMoe

Answer (score 0):

Para empezar  `def nombre(self):`, `def nota(self):` y `def aprobacionNota(self, nota):` están afuera de la clase Alumno. Ya que no están identados. Te faltó la identación en esos métodos.

Por otro lado, tu método ya imprime, así que cuando le ponés `print(alumno1.aprobacionNota(10))`

Lo que hacés es ejecutar esta función `alumno1.aprobacionNota(10)` esa función te imprime si aprobó o no. Esa función no devuelve nada, entonces el print de afuera que está en `print(alumno1.aprobacionNota(10))` no tiene nada para imprimir, y te pone None.

Comment: hola, se ve sin identacion aqui porque no le puse los espacios suficientes, solo lo puse para que se viera como un codigo. Si pero al ejecutar esto alumno1.aprobacionNota() deberia leer esto persona1=Persona('Juana', 8) y con respecto el valor de nota deberia salir si aprobo o no, no es asi?