# ¿Como corregir el output de NONE de las funciones?

Tags: python

Se trata de una practica para hacer un buscador de palabras.
Cuando el programa se ejecuta, ademas del resultado me tira un NONE.

```
text = input()
word = input()
def search(text, word):
  if word in text: 
    print("Word found")
  else: 
    print("Not found")
busca = search( text, word ) 
print( busca )
```

¿Cómo puedo evitar que devuelva None?

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: si search no devuelve nada, entonces que esperas que tenga la variable busca?

Comment: Se devuelve con `return`, `print()` solo imprime por consola, pero no *"devuelve"* nada

Comment: Lo que dijeron Gbianchi y Benito es verdad. Sin embargo, por favor [evita usar imagenes para mostrar código](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2990/un-fragmento-de-c%C3%B3digo-vale-m%C3%A1s-que-mil-im%C3%A1genes-c%C3%B3mo-sensibilizar-a-los-usu)

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Metodos get and set en python](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/495078/metodos-get-and-set-en-python)

Comment: [Desde revicion](https://es.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/304479). Una nota para los que revisen la edicion de Raul en el futuro. [Post relevante en Meta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3151/aceptar-una-edici%c3%b3n-cuando-transcriben-el-c%c3%b3digo-de-una-imagen).

Answer (score 0):

espero esto sea de ayuda.
El none es devuelto ya que la función en si misma no devuelve nada, estas imprimiendo algo, mas no retornando, para esto se utiliza return, quedando tu código algo asi:

```
def search(text, word): #Recuerda que primero se declaran las funciones.
    if word in text:
        return 'Word found'
    else:
        return 'Not found'


text = input()
word = input()
busca = search(text, word)
print(busca)
```